# Is there something like Android's match parent in Delphi?

Tags: android, delphi, user-interface

I want to have components in my android app that will match their parent's size, but I can't find it in the object inspector.

If I use align and anchors it works almost similar, but it's still not as good as android's design.

[image: Object Inspector of Rad XE7]

Comment: You don't need the graphic at all, much less the entire Obj Inspector. You could have included the Anchor settings  in text format, or at least cropped the image to include just the Anchors. Using graphics needlessly is difficult for users behind corporate proxies that can't see them (and therefore can't see the content) or users of mobile devices who must pay for the wasted data used to retrieve the needless or large graphics (and they're difficult to view on small mobile screens). Please use graphics **only when needed** to demonstrate the point because it can't be clearly described in text.

Comment: Can you be more precise about what kind of behavior you find lacking from the properties you've tried? What did you do, what did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: I've cropped the graphic down much smaller (although text would still be preferable) to give you an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `Align` property.

If you want your child control to fill the parent's entire client area, set the `Align` to `Client`. Note this one does not cover the parent control's borders. You probably know about this one from VCL where it was named `alClient`.

If you want your child control to cover the entire parent control, including its borders and such, set `Align` to `Contents`. This one is a new option that was introduced to FMX and is not available in VCL.

You can read more about `Align` options in the oficial documentation:

[FMX.Controls.TControl.Align](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.Align)

[FMX.Types.TAlignLayout](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Types.TAlignLayout)